# ComponentMeasurements

Tags: image-processing

Is someone experienced with Application Nr. 3 shown in the ComponentMeasurements documentation: "Select complete and non-overlapping cells"?

That's the code (you can find the picture "i" in the documentation):

```
b = Binarize[i, {0, .7}]

cells = ComponentMeasurements[
  b, {"Centroid", 
   "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 && 
    50 < #Area < 1200 &]

HighlightImage[i, Circle @@@ cells[[All, 2]]]
```

I want to use this code to find round objects in a picture, but it has not been working that well in some cases. I am attaching an example:

[image: sample image: yellow filled dots and red hollow circles]

Thanks in advance.
[image: Random Bubble Chart]

Comment: Please post the image `i` in your case.

Comment: Your image has several _overlapping_ disks, so I am not completely sure what you want to achieve. However, try this: ``b = GeodesicClosing[Binarize[i, {0, .8}], 30];
cells = ComponentMeasurements[b, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]`` It correctly [identifies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep1RW.png) the non-overlapping circles (but it also finds the overlapping clusters).

Comment: Hi, in this image are only 2 overlapping disks, not several overlapping disks. I want to find all disks that are not overlapping and I don't understand why on one hand the code finds disks where there is actually nothing and on the other hand it doesn't find separated disks.

Comment: @Merlin, you probably didn't post the _original_ image without the red circles, am I correct? Otherwise, the red circles cross the yellow ones several times.

Comment: Yes, the original picture is a bubble chart with yellow disks, the red circles are produced by the code. I am not looking for a solution for that certain picture, it's just an example how the code doesn't work.

Comment: Then please include the original image without the red circles in your question. Have you tried the code I posted above?

Comment: I've uploaded a similar picture, the picture was a random Bubble Chart. Anyway, the picture I actually want to process (and which I cannot share with you) is different from this picture, this is why I am asking for someone who has used that code for image processing and knows how it can be optimised for different tasks. A solution for this picture in particular will not help me in general.

Answer (score 3):

`ComponentMeasurements` will find all *connected components* in the binarized image. That is, every connected "white island". It doesn't care about its shape. The code from the Applications in the documentations *does* also find the overlapping cells, but they are *manually* (!) filtered out by the condition `50 < #Area < 1200 &`. If you remove this condition, even the overlapping cluster is found.

[image: Clusters]

Therefore, you might consider the description of this application ("*Select complete and non-overlapping cells*") slightly misleading.

However, if you are indeed looking for round objects only, you can use property `"Circularity"`, which is defined as "*$2 \pi r/p$, with polygonal length $p$ and equivalent disk radius $r$*". Round objects will have circularity very close to 1.

```
ComponentMeasurements[
  b, {"Centroid", 
   "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 && #Circularity > .9 &];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Domen, that could be helpful, I'll try the code with my pictures.